How do I determine what Fragment or View is responsible for my AppCompatImageButton?
I have a button (AppCompatImageButton) defined inside a toolbar layout (androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar). The toolbar is visible throughout the app. But I'm trying to reference the button in a Fragment to set the listener but the button is null
val myButton = aView.findViewById<View>(R.id.my_button_id)
I suspect either the Fragment or aView is incorrect, which explains why I cannot instantiate the button.
The real question is, how do I determine what Fragment or View is responsible for myButton?
I started by adding my_button to a layout file that already has a working other_button. This other_button is not referenced anywhere else in the project (according to Android Studio search). I figured I would know where to reference my_button and set a listener by following the trail of other_button. So I am a bit lost on how to determine where to set my listener.
